# Why does my Rails website timeout on Windows XP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-xp, passenger

[YayMyLife.com](http://yaymylife.com) is my first Rails site. I am using Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/2.2.2 .

The site works fine on Linux/Mac/Phones. However, it does not load on any browser on XP. This behavior is also found on other XP machines. The browser seems to wait for more content and it times out. I have checked headers with Live HTTPHeaders (the headers look okey) and also flushed DNS cache on XP box.

Can you please help me fix the problem?

Comment: The page loaded in Chrome with no errors. In internet explorer 6 I received a javascript error on line 12 'expected identifier'. After passing that error it displayed.

Comment: Displays fine for me in Chrome, IE7 and FF3 on XP. IE7 does have Javascript issues with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started using Mongrel instead of Passenger and this problem is fixed. Thanks to everybody who took interest; esp. Omar Qureshi

Comment: Passenger release 2.2.3 is a bugfix for broken pipes. I am using nginx and Passenger and the site works fine. Thanks to Phusion team for a timely release.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it doesn't work? I just tried it using IE7 and Firefox 3 within one of my Windows XP virtual machines and the site loads fine. I get a JavaScript error in IE but not in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I got browser shots for those who are interested in solving this case: 
http://browsershots.org/http://www.yaymylife.com/

Answer (score 0):

This gentleman was on #rubyonrails previously and asked the same question, with little feedback

What is the error that you are getting? If you look at all the browsers, they haven't finished loading ... could it be excessive load on the server?

Have you tried getting a Windows machine and trying to test it? If so, what is the error (with screenshot and/or stack trace from your log).

If it was a problem with rails, it would not load on any browser, if it was a css problem it would give you crap on the screen.

This looks to be an excessive load problem and something that you should try and address by looking at the web server end at the amount of time it takes to load the page and whether you need some sort of template caching or to improve the performance of DB queries that are running.

Comment: I tried using Charles Web Debugging Proxy and looks like the response headers are coming in fine but response->body does not get transmitted at all.
At the same time, a page fetch just works fine on a Linux box.